# java Buffereader exit

Tags: java, tcp, buffer

I wonder if someone can help me.
I am getting a return from my server.
I read the lines and get them on the console.
After this I want to get out of the while loop.
I tried it with:

```
> !server.equals("exit")
```

but it doesn't work. 
How can i get out of the loop? 
And start another Buffereader input?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class TCPServer {

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    String clientUserInput;
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(56789);

    while (true) {

        int countUpper = 0;
        int countLower = 0;

        Socket connection   = serverSocket.accept();

        BufferedReader client       = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        DataOutputStream toClient   = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

        clientUserInput = client.readLine();

        System.out.println("Received: " + clientUserInput);


        for(int i = 0; i < clientUserInput.length(); i++) {

            if(Character.isLowerCase(clientUserInput.charAt(i))) {
                countLower++;
            }

            if(Character.isUpperCase(clientUserInput.charAt(i))) {
                countUpper++;
            }       
        }


        InetAddress IPAddress   = connection.getInetAddress();
        int port                = connection.getPort();

        String ausgabe  = " IP-Client: " + IPAddress + "\n" + " Port-Client: " + port + "\n" + " Length: " + clientUserInput.length() + "\n" + " Lowercase letters: " + countLower + "\n" + " Uppercase letters: " + countUpper + "\n";

        toClient.writeBytes(ausgabe);
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class TCPClient {

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    reader();
}

public static void reader() throws UnknownHostException, IOException, InterruptedException {

    String userInput;
    String receivedFromServer;

    Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 56789);

    BufferedReader user             = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    DataOutputStream outToServer    = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    BufferedReader server           = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

    System.out.println("Eingabe: ");

    userInput = user.readLine();
    outToServer.writeBytes(userInput + '\n');

    System.out.println("FROM SERVER ");

    while((receivedFromServer = server.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(receivedFromServer);
        if (userInput.equals("exit")) {
              break;
          }
    }       
  }
}
```

---

My output (for example):

```
Eingabe: 
test output
FROM SERVER 
IP-Client: /127.0.0.1
Port-Client: 59804
Length: 11
Lowercase letters: 10
Uppercase letters: 0
exit
```

But after exit it still is in the loop.

Comment: You should compare `receivedFromServer` with "exit". `server` will never match "exit" (to begin with, it is not a `String`).

Comment: Doesn't work. Still not exiting.

Comment: Okay, I have to ask this, because maybe it is a misunderstanding. Is the server sending the `exit` command or is the client/user typing this command in the prompt? If it is the server, there is no place in your code which actually sends this command to the client....

Comment: Actually this is a good question :D

Comment: Check for extra character at the end of the String. Instead of `System.out.println(receivedFromServer)` do `System.out.println(receivedFromServer + "++")` and see what happens.

Comment: This happens 

FROM SERVER 
 IP-Client: /127.0.0.1++
 Port-Client: 59971++
 Length: 6++
 Lowercase letters: 5++
 Uppercase letters: 0++

Comment: @Freeman if you want to check when the user inputs "exit", then you should move the `userInput = user.readLine();` part also in a loop. So it should be like 1. user input, 2. send, 3. get reply, 4. print reply, repeat

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `break;` in your while loop when you receive `exit`. This will literally break the loop and you can then create new streams or whatever you like. It goes like this:

```
while((receivedFromServer = server.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(receivedFromServer);    
      // check if we got a special signal from the server
      if (receivedFromServer.equals("exit")) {
          break;
      }          
}
```

Comment: Then give a bit more information - are you sure you receive the "exit" signal from the server? Post some output, too.

Answer (score 0):

you have done minor mistake in reading from server. instead of server.equals("exit"), check for receivedFromServer.equals("exit"). As server is BufferedReader object not Exit String which you are expecting.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

    class TCPClient {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        reader();
    }

    public static void reader() throws UnknownHostException, IOException, InterruptedException {

        String userInput;
        String receivedFromServer;

        Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 56789);

        BufferedReader user             = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        DataOutputStream outToServer    = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader server           = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        System.out.println("Eingabe: ");

        userInput = user.readLine();
        outToServer.writeBytes(userInput + '\n');

        System.out.println("FROM SERVER ");

        while((receivedFromServer = server.readLine()) != null && !receivedFromServer.equals("exit")) {
            System.out.println(receivedFromServer);             
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: One problem with this approach is that the "exit" command will not be logged. See my answer (using a `break`) if logging the "exit" command is also wanted.

Comment: @Anton  : This will result same as your answer but in this you don't need to break loop. If exit command is pressed then it will not go into while loop. So it will save some lines of code. (!receivedFromServer.equals("exit")) this condition will check exit command

Comment: I agree, I never said that it does something completely different. I just stated that the "exit" is not going to be printed on the console. The OP has to decide which way to go. Both are doing the job. Regards

Comment: @Anton Yaa i agree with you